# Docker-Compose multiple MAC addresses in containers

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-compose, raspbian, macvlan

I am trying to find a way to run 2 services that uses MAC addresses as unique networkIDs on my SmartThings hub (cast-web-api and MQTT-Bridge)

Right now, I built a docker-compose.yml file that does what I need but I would like to bridge my eth0 to 2 different MAC addresses on the containers.
The goal is to keep DHCP and assign static IP in my router to "Mac1" "Mac2".

I am using Docker version 19.03.1 and docker-compose version 1.24.1

I tried, without success to use "mac_address:"
Also tried to run the interface and the build using that interface using an example like :
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675505/is-it-possible-to-set-a-mac-address-for-docker-build/48676884#48676884)

My file so far (Version 1)

```
mqtt:
    image: arm32v6/eclipse-mosquitto
    volumes:
        - ./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
        - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
        - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    ports:
        - "1883:1883"

mqttbridge:
    image: st_mqtt_bridge
    volumes:
        - ./mqtt-bridge:/config
    ports:
        - "8082:8082"
    links:
        - mqtt

cast-web-api:
    image: cast-web-api
    volumes:
        - ./cast-web/config:/config
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

Would it be possible to achieve what I described previously ?
Maybe Macvlan bridging ? Do I need to upgrade docker-compose to version 2 or 3 ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want `mqttbridge` and `cast-web-api` containers to get a pre-defined MAC address using `docker-compose` file?

Comment: That is exactly right.

To the outside network they would get 2 different IP allowed from the DHCP